# How to implement websocket in Dropwizard

Tags: websocket, dropwizard

I have a requirement to implement websocket with a dropwizard project. However i am unable to find any document related to it. Can any one point out resources for the same.

Answer (score 8):

I've been dealing with the same problem, and thought I would like to share my solution:
http://cvwjensen.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/websockets-in-dropwizard/

I use the Atmosphere framework and the solution defaults to using websockets, but can downgrade to long-polling if required.

That should be enough to get you started...

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do this too. This is the best information I've found so far:

Supposedly one of the most popular websocket frameworks out there works well with Jersey (Jersey is bundled with Dropwizard). You can find more about it here: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Also, someone has published a repository integrating the two of them together: https://github.com/mgutz/dropwizard-atmosphere/

Comment: This example doesn't seem to work for long-polling?

Comment: I'm not sure; I never did get the opportunity to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented websockets into a Dropwizard project by including CometD.

CometD includes a servlet for dealing with WS requests, and Dropwizard exposes the environment to let you register arbitrary servlets.

A small excerpt from my application (Groovy):

```
    environment.addServlet(new Initializer(httpClient, amqpConsumer), "/_initializer")
            .setInitOrder(2)

    environment.addServlet(AnnotationCometdServlet, "/cometd/*")
            .addInitParams([
            transports: 'org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport',
            services: EventService.getCanonicalName(),
            jsonContext: 'org.cometd.server.JacksonJSONContextServer',
            maxSessionsPerBrowser: serviceConfiguration.maxBrowserSessions.toString(),
            maxInterval: '7200',
            logLevel: "2"
    ]).setInitOrder(1)
```

An initializer servlet makes things easy, as shown in the CometD tutorials.